# Calculadora sencilla por consola en batch

Tags: consola, batch

En clase estamos haciendo un ejercicio de hacer una calculadora en `batch`. Yo quería hacer una propia y sencilla, en lugar de coger una por ahí. En teoría debería funcionar, pero lo único que hace cuando meto los datos es poner:

> "echo esta desactivado"

Éste es mi código:

```
@echo off
title Calculadora
echo "Calcualdora"
set/p numero1 = 
set/p operacion= 
set/p numero2 = 
If %operacion%=='+' set/a resultado=%numero1% + %numero2%
If %operacion%=='-' set/a resultado=%numero1% - %numero2%
If %operacion%=='*' set/a resultado=%numero1% * %numero2%
If %operacion%=='/' set/a resultado=%numero1% / %numero2%
echo %resultado%
echo.
pause
exit
```

Comment: ¿Dónde pone lo de echo esta desactivado?

Comment: en cmd cuando lo pruebo

Comment: no añadas la solucion a la pregunta, estando en la respuesta validada es suficiente

Comment: mmm, bueno, es que no esta exactamente como en la respuesta, pero vale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunos fallos. Usa este código:

```
@echo off
title Calculadora
echo "Calculadora"
set resultado= 0
set/p numero1= Introduce el primer numero: 
set/p operacion= Introduce la operacion: 
set/p numero2= Introduce el segundo numero: 
if %operacion%==+ set/a resultado=%numero1% + %numero2%
if %operacion%==- set/a resultado=%numero1% - %numero2%
if %operacion%==* set/a resultado=%numero1% * %numero2%
if %operacion%==/ set/a resultado=%numero1% / %numero2%
echo Resultado %numero1% %operacion% %numero2% = %resultado% 
echo.
pause
```

Comment: El fallo era ese set.... muchas gracias nwn

Comment: Hay más fallos si te fijas en el código:
1.- La asignación debe ir pegado a la variable `var=`
2.- La comparación es sin entrecomillar el carácter
Creo que eso es todo. También puedes cambiar el mensaje porque no está bien escrita "Calculadora" y puedes pedir los números. Voy a ampliar esto último.

Comment: no te molestes, ya esta solucionado y totalmente funcional, modifique un poco lo que pusiste:

Answer (score 0):

Es en la parte `echo %resultado%`
Eso no hace una impresion de `%resultado%`, si quitas "echo" de esa parte, ya no te mostrará ese mensaje.

Comment: Vale... ya no me aparece que esta desactivado.... pero sigue sin mostrar el resultado por pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Se que ya paso un tiempo.. Pero igual quisiera contribuir a la respuesta:

**CAMBIOS**

Al hacer esto simplificamos los codigos anteriores, de manera de que podamos calcular operaciones con solo 2 operandos, o bien, hacer operaciones combinadas

**PD** : Este codigo tiene los cuadros para que sea mas estetico , por decirlo de una forma..

> **AQUI ESTA MI CODIGO:**

```
@echo off
title CALC
color 70
mode con cols=50
mode con lines=15
:inicio
echo  ------------------------------------------------
echo         Welcome to Calculator      
echo  ------------------------------------------------
echo  Escriba la operacion..
set /p sum= 
set /a ans=%sum%
echo.
echo  = %ans%
echo  ------------------------------------------------
ECHO Presione ANY KEY para reiniciar..
pause >nul
cls
goto inicio
```

Comment: Hola @EdGaona. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. En el sitio intentamos tener respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. La idea no es mostrar solamente un fragmento de código, sino además explicar por qué esto solucionaría el problema de la pregunta, al menos una breve descripción. ¿Pensás que podrías **[edit]** tu respuesta agregando algo más de información?

Answer (score -1):

Debes inicializar las variables `numero1` y `numero2`, por ejemplo:

```
set num1=0
set num2=0
```

Comment: No funciona, sigue poniendome que esta desactivado y sin mostrar el resultado